# Google Form to Spreadsheet formula questions (index/match array and 24hr-12hr clock)

Tags: google-sheets, google-forms

I need help with a Google Spreadsheet populated by a Google form.  I cannot get the following formula to work correctly with my form submissions:

```
=(ARRAYFORMULA(if(row(H:H)=1,"Language",(INDEX('INDEX List'!E1:E, MATCH(E2,'INDEX List'!C1:C, 0)))))).
```

Also, I would like to change the date/time form output from a 24hr clock to a 12hr clock, and cannot find anyway to do this without manually changing the number format after each form submission.

Here is the link to the example form/spreadsheet with what I'm trying to do:

- spreadsheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/12glV3Rb8RLzvsf2gRJeIzoFGSBvYetaqU3K_kQMkOLA/edit#gid=1774427561
- form: https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1b_RReJ2GrawGuGRK-_rSsDonZfGwVvfdoqHRJl3tpBQ/edit

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the 12 hour clock, I suggest (i) you may be able to set this in the form and otherwise (ii) select the date/times concerned and Format, Number, More Formats, Custom number format... and:

```
M/d/yyyy H:mm:ss AM/PM
```